# How to this accomplish writing crafty array writing function?

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, recursion

**EDIT**

I know I'm a new poster here, but I'm not new to StackOverflow. I've never seen people make up completely new solutions to problems as I'm seeing below.  I provided the input, the output, and the expected output. The accepted answer will work within these guidelines.

---

I have am trying to write an array writing function that works as described below

```
// existing array
$config = array("preserve" => "please");

function set($key, $value){
    global $config;
    if(count($keys = explode(':', $key)) > 1){
        $key = array_shift($keys);
        while($k = array_pop($keys)){
            $value = array($k => $value);
        }
    }
    return $config[$key] = $value;   
}

// set
set("foo", "bar");
set("pokemon:trainer", "ashk");
set("pokemon:favorite", "diglett"); // overwrites pokemon:trainer :(

print_r($config);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [preserve] => please
    [foo] => bar
    [pokemon] => Array
        (
            [favorite] => diglett
        )

)
```

**Oh no! Who's the pokemon trainer? Ash Ketchum has been forgotten!**

---

I understand why it's breaking, but I can't find out how I should write this function.  I sense the need for recursion, but I'm not sure how to implement it :\

Output **should** be

```
Array
(
    [preserve] => please
    [foo] => bar
    [pokemon] => Array
        (
            [trainer] => ashk
            [favorite] => diglett
        )

)
```

Comment: I don't see a description. What is this code supposed to do? That is, what is the input and what is the output supposed to be?

Comment: @JimMischel Sorry about that, I added the expected output.

Comment: I don't remember Ash ever training Diglett.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I have over 100 rep, I can finally post this as a real answer and mark it as accepted.

This is quite a neat little snippet :)

```
// existing array
$config = array("preserve" => "please");

function set($key, $value){
    global $config;
    if(count($keys = explode(':', $key)) > 1){
        $key = array_shift($keys);
        while($k = array_pop($keys)){
            $value = array($k => $value);
        }
        // *** fixed here ***
        // merge new data with possible existing data
        if(array_key_exists($key, $config)){
            $value = array_merge_recursive($config[$key], $value);
        }
    }
    return $config[$key] = $value;   
}

// set
set("foo", "bar");
set("pokemon:trainer", "ashk");
set("pokemon:favorite", "diglett"); // no longer overwrites pokemon:trainer :)

print_r($config);
```

Answer (score 3):

seems like working with objects would be much easier.

```
$config = new stdClass();
$config->preserve = 'please';
$config->foo = 'bar';

$config->pokemon = new stdClass();
$config->pokemon->trainer= 'ashk';
$config->pokemon->favorite = 'diglette';

var_dump($config);
```

or better yet, create a custom class that behaves exactly how you want with methods and protected data.

Edit:

maybe something like this. you could of course make it behave however you like.

```
class config {
   protected $preserve;
   protected $data = array();
   protected $pokemonData = array();

   public function __construct($preserve) {
      $this->preserve = $preserve;
   }

   public function set($key, $value) {
      $this->data[$key] = $value;
   }

   public function setPokemon($key, $value) {
      $this->pokemonData[$key] = $value;
   }

   public function get($key) {
      if (isset($this->data[$key]) === true) {
         return $this->data[$key];
      } else {
         return false;
      }
   }

   public function getPokemon($key) {
      if (isset($this->pokemonData[$key]) === true) {
         return $this->pokemonData[$key];
      } else {
         return false;
      }
   }

   public function getAsArray() {
      $output = array(
         'preserve' => $this->preserve,
         'pokemon' => $this->pokmonData
      );
      return $output + $this->data;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$config = array('preserve' => 'please');

function set($config, $key, $value) {
    $keys = explode(':', $key);
    $left_key = array_shift($keys);
    if (count($keys) === 0) {
        $config[$left_key] = $value;
    } else {
        if (isset($config[$left_key]) === false) $config[$left_key] = array();
        $config[$left_key] = set($config[$left_key], implode(':', $keys), $value);
    }
    return $config;
}
```

usage:

```
$config = set($config, $key, $value);
```

edit with pass by reference operator:

```
// change to this
function set(&$config, $key, $value) {

// also this line
$config[$left_key] = set($config[$left_key], implode(':', $keys), $value);
// would then need to be this instead
set($config[$left_key], implode(':', $keys), $value);
```

new usage:

```
set($config, $key, $value);
```

Comment: its a recursive function, which is why you need to add the config as an input instead of relying on the global keyword. keep in mind if you do successive calls like `set('foo', 'test'); set('foo:bar', 'test');` it will give you an error, as you should expect.

Comment: you could also use the `&` reference operator next to $config in the arguments to avoid needing to set the config each time you use the function.

Comment: this also allows you to do calls like `set('foo:bar:baz', 'somevalue');`

Answer (score 0):

When you do `set("pokemon:???", "someVal");` you are writing over the previous set `pokemon` array within `$config`. Perhaps you can add some kind of counter/id in the `key`

```
function set($key, $value){
    global $config;
    if(count($keys = explode(':', $key)) > 1){
        $key = array_shift($keys);
        while($k = array_pop($keys)){
            $value = array($k => $value);
        }
        $config[$key][] = $value;
        return;
    }
    $config[$key] = $value;   
}
```

Comment: As I said, I understand **why** it's happening... I just don't know how to make it work as expected.

Comment: No, you can't add a counter to the key.  The user will be expecting to retrieve the value based on the same key they entered.

Comment: Shredder, I provided the expected output.

Comment: thank you.  This is not the solution that worked for me, but it prompted me to arrive at the proper one.  I have less than 100 rep so I can't answer my own question. Instead, I added an edit to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
$config = array("preserve" => "please");

function set($key, $value){
    global $config;
    if(strpos($key,':')==true) { 
        $config[substr($key,0,strpos($key,':'))][substr($key,strpos($key,':')+1)] = $value;
    }
    else {
        $config[$key] = $value;
    }
}
set("foo", "bar");
set("pokemon:trainer", "ashk");
set("pokemon:favorite", "diglett"); // overwrites pokemon:trainer :(

print_r($config);
```

As long as you only have one : in your input, this works.

Comment: Thank you for this, but the user could specify as many `:` in their key as they'd like.

Comment: Too bad. I'm sorry this didn't help.

Comment: Added the proper answer to the OP.